# SQL Next Available PK in an Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to insert a bunch of records from one table (which I'll call **tblSource** for this example) into another table (**tblDestination**) using an INSERT INTO .. SELECT query, but I have to manually increment the key values that I'm inserting into **tblDestination** rather than just setting it to IDENTITY, because **tblDestination** uses a compound key.  So I have a function that's run from inside the SELECT that finds **tblDestination**'s current maximum key value, increments it by 1, and returns the value.

The function looks like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNextStringID] ()
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @nextstringid INT

SELECT @nextstringid = MAX(StringID) FROM tblDestination
IF (@nextstringid IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @nextstringid = 0
END 
SET @nextstringid = @nextstringid + 1

RETURN @nextstringid
END
```

My INSERT INTO .. SELECT statement, where this is being called, looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblDestination(StringID, StringText)
SELECT dbo.GetNextStringID(), StringText FROM tblSource
```

The problem is, this causes a Primary Key conflict, because the function is only run once and the same PK value is used for all rows of the insert.

Is there a better way to do this?  I could add the PK from **tblSource** to the @nextstringid variable instead of 1, but that creates the possibility of PKs jumping several numbers at a time rather than incrementing by 1, which is pretty messy. Maybe I could use the row number for each row of **tblSource**? Is there an easy way to do that?

I should note also that I'm aware this creates a race condition where there will be key conflicts if this query is run from several places at once.  It's wrapped in a transaction to ensure it rolls back if there's a problem.

**SOLUTION:**

I've now taken out the following line from my function:

```
SET @nextstringid = @nextstringid + 1
```

Which means that it now just returns the maximum ID in **tblDestination**

And I'm now adding the current row in the INSERT INTO .. SELECT query like so:

```
INSERT INTO tblDestination(StringID, StringText)
SELECT dbo.GetNextStringID() + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tblSource.ID), StringText 
FROM tblSource
```

Comment: You may want to revise your example. You're trying to insert **from** destination **into** source.

Comment: Seems correct to me.  I'm doing INSERT INTO tblDestination FROM tblSource.  Maybe you're confused about the function, where I'm doing a SELECT .. FROM tblDestination?  If that's the case, it's because I'm getting the current highest ID in tblDestination, and incrementing it by 1, to get the next available ID, which I'm using as my ID for when I do the insertion.

Comment: @Damien Nevermind, I see what you mean.  Updated.

Comment: No, I'm confused because your first sentences say that you're inserting **from** destination **into** source. It seems the wrong way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get row number you can use sql server's row_number function

Here is a sample code to demonstrate what you need... instead of 3 use the @nextstringid variable you already have and you should be good.

```
create table tblSource(id integer identity, StringText varchar(200))
insert into tblSource values ('test1')
insert into tblSource values ('test2')
insert into tblSource values ('test3')
insert into tblSource values ('test4')
SELECT (row_number()  over (order by id)) + 3 , id, StringText FROM tblSource t where t.id in (2,4)
```

Notice i selected #2 and #4 but the row number will still give two consecutive ids (in this case 1+3 and 2+3 (4 and 5)

Hope it helps.